# Very long layover at London Heathrow T3

Tags: usa, layovers, lhr

I have a very long (17 hours) layover at London Heathrow. I'll be arriving at terminal 3 and my connecting flight to LAX is also from terminal 3.

I arrive 20:00 hrs and depart 12:00 hrs (12 PM) the next day.

I have the following questions:

1. Sleeping options at T3. I'm on the down low money wise so looking for something not too heavy on the pocket.
2. Is moving from one terminal to another allowed? If so, I will be fine moving around the place (heck I've got 17 hours here!) if I can find better sleeping pods/lounges elsewhere.

I am NOT looking at landside options so there's that.

Comment: See eg https://www.sleepinginairports.net/sleep-guide/sleeping-in-london-heathrow-airport.htm

Comment: What time do you arrive and depart LHR? The terminals close overnight so you may have to go landside.

Comment: @JoeMalt I arrive 20:00 hrs and depart 12:00 hrs (12 PM) the next day. I will update my question too.

Comment: What is the actual itinerary/airline(s)? A 17 hour layover sounds a long time for a connected flight (one PNR)

Comment: @Traveller same PNR different airlines. Route sharing agreement I guess

Comment: Just nit-picking, but 20:00 to 12:00 is **16** hours.

Answer (score 3):

Last time I passed through LHR they had a lot of benches on which one could sit semi-flat. Some of them were in the more secluded areas of the terminal (T5, in my case), so definitely a good option to take a nap at night. In fact I saw a lot of people taking naps there, even during the day. There are some pictures [here](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/sleep-guide/sleeping-in-london-heathrow-airport.htm). AFAIK LHR terminals do not close, i.e.: you won't be asked to leave. At least that is my impression from my travel through it before COVID.

There's also [an hotel](https://www.myaerotel.com/en-uk/find/americas-europe/united-kingdom/london/aerotel-london) (land-side) attached to T3.

Comment: @litteadv Will I be allowed to book a room at this hotel?

Answer (score 1):

I once ended up in a totally unplanned layover in Heathrow for ~15 hours, overnight. I simply sat in a seating area among lots of other people, read, watched TV, and napped a little. The seating area felt safe and reasonably comfortable. I'd do it again. You may want to consider this option.

Comment: I am a bit of a sensitive sleeper and find it hard to nap in a place bustling with people like an airport terminal. Which is why I'm looking for options where I can get a little seclusion